# I had a custom H:M:S field type in excel when loaded in R it turned to a bizarre number. How do i return it back to the time I had before?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, time

My original entry in the cell was

```
12:23:40 AM
```

When i loaded it with the read_excel function it turned into

```
1.6435185185186188E-2
```

The same situation happened for multiple rows. I tried doing this

```
df$time <- strftime(df$time, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

I got

```
invalid 'trim' argument
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given is in decimal days.

The 1.6435...E-2 is the portion of 1 day represented by 12:23:40 AM.
One day is 86400 seconds, 12:23:40 AM is 1420 seconds after midnight.

1420/86400 = 1.643518...E-2

To get back to seconds-since-midnight, multiply your number by 86400. You should be able to convert back to whatever format you want from there.

Comment: I was able to convert to the numbers but then i get this error message Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: I tried the 1970-01-01 and 1899-12-30 but both give me 00:00:00

Comment: Dates without times are associated with the beginning of the day, hence 00:00:00. Using modulo arithmetic, any date without a time is an integer number of days and in seconds will be a multiple of 86400, and thus will convert to 00:00:00.

Comment: I know but i'm trying to get the hours that i had in excel prior to when i loaded them up in R.